# Let controller action in Asp.Net Mvc 3 handle jQuery post as well as "traditional post"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a controller action that listens to POSTs. The post can of two types:

- jQuery
- traditional form posts

If jQuery posts, returning result should be HttpStatusCodeResult, else ViewResult.

What's the preferred way of setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [IsAjaxRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest.aspx). This tells you it it's a traditional post or an AJAX post.

Comment: since I don't want this to lie in each action, supporting this behavior, where's the best place to hook into?

Comment: You could add an actionfilter and handle things there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of the preferred way. But I would make my distinction when handling the POST action by Content-Type and return the appropriate response based on that.

Use application/json for jQuery Ajax and multipart for the html post.